# How to upgrade ocamls package ocamlc-loc to 3.7.0 or higher to end conflict with ocaml-lsp-server?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocaml-dune

Im trying to install ocaml-lsp-server but i get this error:

**input: opam install ocaml-lsp-server

output: [ocaml-lsp-server.1.14.2] no changes from git+https://github.com/ocaml/oc
aml-lsp.git

The following dependencies couldn't be met:

- ocaml-lsp-server → ocamlc-loc >= 3.7.0
  no matching version

No solution found, exiting**

I've tried to upgrade ocamlc-loc but there is no version after 3.5.0

**input: opam upgrade ocamlc-loc

output: Already up-to-date.
Nothing to do.
**
I've also tried installing other versions of ocaml-lsp-server but i get this:

**input: opam install ocaml-lsp-server.1.10.5

output: [ocaml-lsp-server.1.14.2] no changes from git+https://github.com/ocaml/oca
ml-lsp.git

[ERROR] ocaml-lsp-server = 1.10.5 not available because the package is
pinned to version 1.14.2**

Im running windows 10 and ocaml at version 4.14.0

What can i do now?

Comment: I'm not on windows or that version of ocaml, so I can't offer any direct details. But try `opam update` to make sure your definitions are up-to-date first.